# How to run a cumulative/rolling average with a pandas groupby?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some ordered data that I want to `.groupby()` and obtain a cumulative/rolling average for each group. Here is an example of my data:

```
    player_id   gp  time    shot_zone_basic shot_made_flag
0   1630462 1   1616    Mid-Range   0
1   1630462 1   1851    Above the Break 3   0
2   1630462 1   1982    Restricted Area 0
3   1630462 1   2024    Right Corner 3  0
4   1630462 2   512 Restricted Area 0
5   1630462 2   714 Above the Break 3   0
6   1630462 2   1121    Restricted Area 0
7   1630462 3   354 Above the Break 3   1
8   1630462 3   401 Restricted Area 1
9   1630462 3   467 Restricted Area 1
10  1630462 3   564 Mid-Range   0
11  1630462 3   1116    Right Corner 3  0
12  1630462 3   1125    Right Corner 3  0
13  1630462 3   1194    Above the Break 3   0
14  1630462 3   1683    Above the Break 3   0
15  1630462 4   527 In The Paint (Non-RA)   0
16  1630462 4   683 Above the Break 3   1
17  1630462 4   779 Right Corner 3  0
18  1630462 4   1998    Restricted Area 1
19  1630462 5   898 Above the Break 3   1
```

Here is a dict of it to load:

```
{'gp': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 3, 
        11: 3, 12: 3, 13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 4, 16: 4, 17: 4, 18: 4, 19: 5}, 
 'player_id': {0: 1630462, 1: 1630462, 2: 1630462, 3: 1630462, 4: 1630462, 
               5: 1630462, 6: 1630462, 7: 1630462, 8: 1630462, 9: 1630462, 
               10: 1630462, 11: 1630462, 12: 1630462, 13: 1630462, 14: 1630462, 
               15: 1630462, 16: 1630462, 17: 1630462, 18: 1630462, 19: 1630462}, 
 'shot_made_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 
                    10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 1, 17: 0, 18: 1, 19: 1}, 
 'shot_zone_basic': {0: 'Mid-Range', 1: 'Above the Break 3', 2: 'Restricted Area', 
                     3: 'Right Corner 3', 4: 'Restricted Area', 5: 'Above the Break 3', 
                     6: 'Restricted Area', 7: 'Above the Break 3', 8: 'Restricted Area', 
                     9: 'Restricted Area', 10: 'Mid-Range', 11: 'Right Corner 3', 
                     12: 'Right Corner 3', 13: 'Above the Break 3', 14: 'Above the Break 3', 
                     15: 'In The Paint (Non-RA)', 16: 'Above the Break 3', 17: 'Right Corner 3', 
                     18: 'Restricted Area', 19: 'Above the Break 3'}, 
 'time': {0: 1616, 1: 1851, 2: 1982, 3: 2024, 4: 512, 5: 714, 6: 1121, 7: 354, 8: 401, 
          9: 467, 10: 564, 11: 1116, 12: 1125, 13: 1194, 14: 1683, 15: 527, 16: 683, 17: 
          779, 18: 1998, 19: 898}}
```

With the data in this order (ordered by player `player_id`, games played `gp` and time elapsed since the start of that respective game `time`), I'd like to group by `player_id` (there's more than 1 player_id in my full data), `shot_zone_basic`, and `shot_made_flag` to calculate a cumulative or rolling average of `shot_made_flag` for each `shot_zone_basic` for each `player_id`

My desired output for a cumulative average would thus be

```
    player_id   gp  time    shot_zone_basic  shot_made_flag     shot_zone_avg
0   1630462     1   1616    Mid-Range                     0                 0
1   1630462     1   1851    Above the Break 3             0                 0
2   1630462     1   1982    Restricted Area               0                 0
3   1630462     1   2024    Right Corner 3                0                 0
4   1630462     2   512     Restricted Area               0                 0
5   1630462     2   714     Above the Break 3             0                 0
6   1630462     2   1121    Restricted Area               0                 0
7   1630462     3   354     Above the Break 3             1               0.5
8   1630462     3   401     Restricted Area               1              0.33
9   1630462     3   467     Restricted Area               1               0.5                                
10  1630462     3   564     Mid-Range                     0                 0
11  1630462     3   1116    Right Corner 3                0                 0
12  1630462     3   1125    Right Corner 3                0                 0
13  1630462     3   1194    Above the Break 3             0              0.33
14  1630462     3   1683    Above the Break 3             0              0.25
15  1630462     4   527     In The Paint (Non-RA)         0                 0
16  1630462     4   683     Above the Break 3             1              0.20
17  1630462     4   779     Right Corner 3                0                 0
18  1630462     4   1998    Restricted Area               1              0.40
19  1630462     5   898     Above the Break 3             1              0.16
```

Again, I'd like to calculate a cumulative average for each `shot_zone_basic` for each player in my data. How would you also do this for a rolling average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `groupby` + `expanding.mean`:

```py
tmp = df.groupby(['player_id', 'shot_zone_basic'])['shot_made_flag'].expanding().mean()
df['shot_zone_avg'] = tmp.droplevel([0,1]).round(2)
df['shot_zone_avg_of_until_current'] = tmp.groupby(level=[0,1]).shift().droplevel([0,1]).round(2)
```

Output:

```py
    gp  player_id  shot_made_flag        shot_zone_basic  time  shot_zone_avg_of_until_current
0    1    1630462               0              Mid-Range  1616                             NaN
1    1    1630462               0      Above the Break 3  1851                             NaN
2    1    1630462               0        Restricted Area  1982                             NaN
3    1    1630462               0         Right Corner 3  2024                             NaN
4    2    1630462               0        Restricted Area   512                            0.00  
5    2    1630462               0      Above the Break 3   714                            0.00
6    2    1630462               0        Restricted Area  1121                            0.00
7    3    1630462               1      Above the Break 3   354                            0.00
8    3    1630462               1        Restricted Area   401                            0.00
9    3    1630462               1        Restricted Area   467                            0.25
10   3    1630462               0              Mid-Range   564                            0.00
11   3    1630462               0         Right Corner 3  1116                            0.00
12   3    1630462               0         Right Corner 3  1125                            0.00
13   3    1630462               0      Above the Break 3  1194                            0.33
14   3    1630462               0      Above the Break 3  1683                            0.25 
15   4    1630462               0  In The Paint (Non-RA)   527                             NaN
16   4    1630462               1      Above the Break 3   683                            0.20
17   4    1630462               0         Right Corner 3   779                            0.00
18   4    1630462               1        Restricted Area  1998                            0.40
19   5    1630462               1      Above the Break 3   898                            0.33
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. However, there is one minor edit I realized. At any given point, I want the average to be up to that point. So for example, for rows 1,5,7 the result you have is 0,0,0.33. That is taking into account the average through the observation as the outcome is 0,0,1 (which is where the 0.33 comes from) Is there a way to shift this so that the value calculated is UP TO and not through the current point? So example rows 1,5,7 would be NAN,0,0 and then row 13 would be 0.33 since up to that point the outcomes are 0,0,1... My fault on not initially phrasing it this way

Comment: I think to solve this I would just need to add `.shift(periods=1)` correct?

Comment: Looks like adding the shift to the end just shifts the entire dataframe, which is not what I want. I need to place the shift somewhere else I think

Comment: @bismo I edited the answer. To restrict the shift to each group, you need `groupby` again.